# How to use services for a form fieldset in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, service-locator, zend-framework-mvc, servicemanager

I have a form ([`Zend\Form\Form`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Form.php)) with some nested fieldsets ([`Zend\Form\Fieldset`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Fieldset.php)) in it. The construction is pretty similar to that in the [Form Collections tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html).

```
Storage\Form\MyForm
|_'Storage\Form\Fieldset\FooFieldset'
  |_'Storage\Form\Fieldset\BarFieldset'
|_'Storage\Form\Fieldset\BazFieldset'
...
```

**`MyForm`**

```
class MyForm {
    public function __construct()
    {
        ...
        $this->add(
            [
                'type' => 'Storage\Form\Fieldset\FooFieldset',
                'options' => [
                    'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**`FooFieldset`**

```
class FooFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('foo');
        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator())->setObject(new Foo()); // dependencies!
    }
}
```

It works, but the fieldset class has two dependencies in it. I want to inject them. In order to do it, I created a `FooFieldsetFactory` and extended the `/module/MyModule/config/module.config.php` by:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Storage\Form\Fieldset\FooFieldset' => 'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Factory\FooFieldsetFactory',
    ],
],
```

The factory is simply being ignored. I guess, the service locator first tries to find the class by namespace and only if nothing is found, takes a look in the `invokables` and `factories`. OK. Then I created an alias:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Storage\Form\Fieldset\FooFieldset' => 'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Factory\FooFieldsetFactory',
    ],
],
'aliases' => [
    'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Foo' => 'Storage\Form\Fieldset\FooFieldset',
],
```

... and tried to use it instead of `Storage\Form\Fieldset\FooFieldset` in my form class. But now I get an exception:

> Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Storage\Form\Fieldset\Foo

I've also tried this directly:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Foo' => 'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Factory\FooFieldsetFactory',
    ],
],
```

No effect, the same error.

And this also didn't work (the same error):

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Foo' => 'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Factory\FooFieldsetFactory',
    ],
],
```

So the referencing a service for a fieldset seems not to work. Or am I doing something wrong?

**How to use services for form fieldsets?**

---

**UPDATE**

With some debuggin I found out, that my `Foo` fieldset factory cannot be found, because it has not be added to the `factories` list of the [`Zend\Form\FormElementManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/FormElementManager.php). Here is the place in the [`Zend\Form\Factory`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Factory.php#L111):

[image]

So my config

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Foo' => 'Storage\Form\Fieldset\Factory\FooFieldsetFactory',
    ],
],
```

is ignored. How to fix this?

---

**UPDATE** Additional information, how I'm creating my `Form` object.

**`/module/Foo/config/module.config.php`**

```
return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            'Foo\Controller\My' => 'Foo\Controller\Factory\MyControllerFactory'
        ]
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'Foo\Form\MyForm' => 'Foo\Form\Factory\MyFormFactory',
        ],
    ],
];
```

**`/module/Foo/src/Foo/Form/Factory/MyFormFactory.php`**

```
namespace Foo\Form\Factory;

use ...;

class MyFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $form = new MyForm();
        $form->setAttribute('method', 'post')
            ->setHydrator(new ClassMethods())
            ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());
        return $form;
    }
}
```

**`/module/Foo/src/Foo/Controller/Factory/MyControllerFactory.php`**

```
namespace Foo\Controller\Factory;

use ...;

class MyControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $fooPrototype = new Foo();
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        // $myForm = $realServiceLocator->get('Foo\Form\MyForm'); <-- This doesn't work correctly for this case. The FormElementManager should be used instead.
        $formElementManager = $realServiceLocator->get('FormElementManager');                        
        $myForm = $formElementManager->get('Foo\Form\MyForm');
        return new MyController($myForm, $fooPrototype);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is because you are adding your form elements in the forms  `__construct()` method rather than `init()` [as suggested in the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html).

> You can use a factory instead of an invokable in order to handle dependencies in your elements/fieldsets/forms.
>
> And now comes the first catch.
>
> If you are creating your form class by extending `Zend\Form\Form`, you must not add the custom element in the `__construct`-or (as we have done in the previous example where we used the custom element’s FQCN), but rather in the `init()` method:

The *reason* is that the new form's factory (which is used to create new elements using `add()`) must have the application's form element manager [injected *after* the form's constructor has been called](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/FormElementManager.php#L243) This form element manager instance contains all the references to your custom forms elements which are registered under the `form_elements` configuration key.

By calling `add()` in the form `__construct` [the form factory will lazy load a *new instance* of the form element manager](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Factory.php#L89); which will be able to create all default form elements but will not have any knowledge of your custom form element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I moved the initialization logic from the constructor into the `init()`. But it's not working. For the **`Form`** the elements are just not found, e.g.: `No element by the name of [foo] found in form`. For **`FieldSet`s**: The same error, as before: `Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Order\Form\Fieldset\Foo`.

Comment: I also analyzed the state of the `FormElementManager` in the `init()`. Since the `init()` is called after the constructor, I expected to find my custom fieldset factories in `MyFieldset->factory->formElementManager->factories`. But the property only contains the standard Zend factories.

Comment: @automatix Are you creating the *form* using `$formElementManager->get('Order\Form\Fieldset\Foo`);` with `Order\Form\Fieldset\Foo` registered in `form_elements`? You question only shows `Storage\Form\Fieldset\Foo`.

Comment: Just updated the question. I've been creating the `Form` directly from the `ServiceManager`. Just changed this to cretaing via `FormElementManager`. Now I can create the fields in the `Form#init()` and my `FooFieldsetFactory` is finally getting retrieved! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @automatix how did you fixed the problem with the "No element by the name.." ?
I do `$form->get('employee')` which gives me the exception.
My EmployeeFieldSet does in the constructor:
`parent::__construct('employee');`
In the init function I do all those `add` calls.
In my form's  constructor I do this:
`parent::__construct('create_employee');`
and within the init() method I add the `EmployeeFieldSet`.
in the config.module.php I have the `form_elements` but it won't get called

Comment: @rogaa I do nothing with the constructor and only use the `form_elements` config key (e.g. `'form_elements'.'factories'.'My\Fieldset\Bar' => 'My\Fieldset\Factory\BarFactory'`) and add the `Fieldset` within the `init()` (e.g. `$this->add(['name' => 'bar', 'type' => 'My\Fieldset\Bar', ...])`). In the views script I call then the `Fieldset` like this: `$fooFieldset->get('bar')`. Oh, now whhen writing this comment, I think I see your mistake. It's the `name` parameter -- you should pass this to your parent `Fieldset`. Otherwise the `FooFieldset`'s `get(...)` of doesn't know, what to retrieve.

Comment: @automatix is your updated question still correct with your FormFactory? Sorry for bothering you again - I removed my construct() methods from my `EmployeeForm` and my `EmployeeFieldset` but I'm still getting the same error output.
What do you mean with the `name` parameter?
In my `EmployeeForm->init()` I do the following: `$this->add([
            'name' => 'employee',
            'type' => EmployeeFieldset::class,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ],
        ]);`

Comment: Ok I got it .. my oh my.. I added a DI to my `IndexController` to retrieve the form via the `FormElementManager` (in the `IndexControllerFactory`).

But well I forgot to change the form call in my action - I still created the form object via `new EmployeeForm();` instead of calling `this->form` due to the DI...

Anyway thanks @automatix !

Comment: @rogaa I don't see any differences between your `add(...)` call and mine. But I've just updated my question and corrected the way I'm retrieving `MyForm` object from the `ServiceManager`. Oh, you were faster with your comment... :) OK, is working now?